# How to embed the pymol module into python?

Tags: python

I installed the `pymol` at
`E:\{my\folder\directory}\pymol2\PyMOL-2.3.2_81-Win64-portable-py37\PyMOL\PyMOLWin.exe`

`python` is installed at
`C:\Python36`

However, when running the `python` script in `Pycharm`, the `import pymol` gets error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymol'`.  I think, this is because the `pymol` module is not embedded into the `python` environment.

Can I ask how to embed the `pymol` module into `python`?

Answer (score 1):

In PyMOL support [FAQ's](https://pymol.org/2/support.html?) it says that PyMOL will most likely not work with system Python installations.

However, PyMOL comes with a python distribution that should be located in this directory. (`E:\{my\folder\directory}\pymol2\PyMOL-2.3.2_81-Win64-portable-py37\PyMOL\python.exe`). This has the PyMOL python package amongst others (NumPy, BioPython, ... everything in `PyMOL\Lib\site-packages`) ready installed. PyMOL is shipped with the conda package manager so if you're missing a package you can use the `Conda-Prompt` to install it with conda.

If you already have an Anaconda distribution you could as install directly with:

`conda install -c schrodinger pymol-bundle`

Then, you just need to change the project interpreter in PyCharm and you're away!

Comment: Thank you, I think you are correct, I am managing the Anaconda now.